# Performance of building complex angular templates

Tags: performance, angular

I'm currently updating an angularJS 1 app to angular 4 and have stumbled upon a huge performance loss in angular 4 compared to angular 1. Imagine this template:

```
<dt *ngIf="auftrag?.project?.termin.aProperty">Title of aProperty</dt>
<dd *ngIf="auftrag?.project?.termin.aProperty">{{order?.project?.termin?.aProperty}}</dd>
```

There are 56 properties on the "order" object that should be displayed when they are set and not displayed at all when they are not set. So I have at least 112 ngIf conditions on 112 elements that need to be inserted into the DOM separately, plus some additional DOM elements and some *ngFor uses around it to make it look good.

In the old angular1 app this takes 60ms of raw scripting time on my machine to render (according to Chrome timeline).

In Angular 4 RC5 this takes around 250ms of raw scripting time (give or take a few more or less) and around 180ms after compiling it with AOT. Whats worse is, that I have a noticable delay to render this template on an iPhone while the angular 1 version feels like its instantaneous.

The angular4 component is already using OnPush changedetection. There is no difference in performance when I use angular 2.4.10.

In Angular1 I used "ng-show" as a performance improvement on every element. The angular2 equivalent in setting a "hidden" class when the condition is false doesn't change much in the scripting time (like so: < dt [class.hidden]="!order.cProperty>...< /dt>)

When I look into Chrome timeline of my angular 4 app, most of the time is spent in ZoneTask.invoke but it has almost no self-time. In fact there is almost no task which as any self-time. I don't really know whats going on here.

Where is the time spent? How can I make it faster?

[image: Screenshot of Timeline]

Comment: there is no regression in a RC. Like I have mentioned, there is no significant change in performance when I use angular 2.4.10

Comment: Sorry, had misread, thought you were coming from an earlier 2.x.

Comment: I'm experiencing bad performance too, up to a second of lag when creating  a Material2 list with 80 items on low end devices. Had to fall back on a lazy loaded list. I first built my app with vanilla js & material lite and it was instantaneous.